# Python error in generating and sorting 4 cases of random variables

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to simulate a continuous randomly generated number distribution in Python and find the combined numbers (where y=x1+x2) fall within p(0.9

```
n = 10000
x11 = [random.random() for i in range(n)]
x12 = [random.random() for i in range(n)]
x21 = [-0.5*(log(1-random.random())) for i in range(n)]
x22 = [-0.5*(log(1-random.random())) for i in range(n)]
x31 = [random.random() for i in range(n)]
x32 = [random.uniform(0,2) for i in range(n)]
x41 = [0.25 if random.random() < 0.8 else 1.5 for r in range(n)]
x42 = [0.25 if random.random() < 0.8 else 1.5 for r in range(n)]
```

x11 through x42 are pairs of cases that I'm trying to get the probability that they'll fall between 0.9 and 1.8 where the pairs of lists generated are combined and then operated on.  So x11 and x12 are combined and then expected value, variance, and the 0.9 to 1.8 p(x) is found.

```
def test():
  x1,x2,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
  for i in range(10000):
    if random.random()< 0.8:
      x1 += 0.25
    else:
      x2 += 1.5
    y = x1 + x2
    if y>0.9 and y<=1.8:
      c = c + 1
  return x1,x2,c

print "test: ",test()

def sim(a,b):
  #pyab1 = sum([a for a in a if a>0.9 and a<=1.8])/10000
  #pyab2 = sum([b for b in b if b>0.9 and b<=1.8])/10000
  #print "*****",float(pyab1+pyab2)
  #print a+b
  #array1 = [[a],[b]]
  array1 = a+b
  #array1.extend(a)
  #array1.extend(b)
  #c = 0
  #for y in array1:
    #if y>0.9 and y<=1.8:
      #c = c + 1
  pyab = sum([y for y in array1 if y>0.9 and y<=1.8])/10000
  print("P(a < x <= b) : {0:8.4f}".format(pyab))
```

I'm only counting the probability P(0.9<%Y<=1.8) so the count has to fall within those values.  The 1-random.random() was only for that case, when I tried using that for all the cases they still came up with the wrong values.  Here's the theoretical outcomes and you can see how it's different:

> y~u(0,1) 
>   = 0.575
>
> y~exp(2) 
>   = 0.3371
>
> x1~u(0,1)
>   x2~u(0,2)
>
> P(y=0.25)=0.8
>   P(y=1.5)=0.2
>   = 0.2

Here's the output followed by the values it's supposed to give, but this shows how far off the results are.

```
case 1: P(a < x <= b) : 0.7169 #should be 0.575 
case 2: P(a < x <= b) : 0.4282 #should be 0.3371 
case 3: P(a < x <= b) : 0.5966 #should be 0.4413 
case 4: P(a < x <= b) : 0.5595 #should be 0.2
```

I'm very new to Python so please be patient if my question seems to have an obvious solution that I missed.

Comment: I don't understand completely what you need. How is sim() called, can you put a snippet of code show how it's called, the expected output, and then the actual output.

Comment: Just added it. It cut off the top above my code where I go into the purpose.  I'll reiterate it here so its visible.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a continuous randomly generated number distribution in Python and find the combined numbers (where y=x1+x2) fall within p(0.9<y<=1.8).  x41 and x42 are independently generated (but with the same Python characteristics of 0,1 continuous).  You'll find about 3 different methods attempted in the code below.  The problem is that the x11,x12 pair (where y=x41+x42) have a p(a<y<=b) which is way too low, it should be around 0.575 and I've been trying to find the bug in this code for a little while. The x41,x42 pair for p(0.9<y<=1.8) should be around 0.2 but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably you'd better replace

```
pyab = sum([y for y in array1 if y>0.9 and y<=1.8])/10000
```

with

```
pyab = len([y for y in array1 if y>0.9 and y<=1.8])/len(array1)
```

since you need the probabilities, but not the sum of the actual values. also, the `len(array1)` most probably is not 10000, but the combined length of two arrays.

Comment: sorry, but it's still giving all incorrect values except for the x21,x22 pair (which were correct before the edit as well). It cut off the top of my post before my code where I say it's 2 independently generated numbers that are summed (y=x1+x2) so that 'y' is then compared to fall between 0.9 and 1.8 for each pass of the for loop.

Comment: `array1 = a+b` does not sum arrays, you should use `array1 = [sum(i) for i in zip(a,b)]` instead

Comment: no sorry that still gives the wrong values. i'm concerned there might be a problem with the logic of the code.

Comment: can you show the results you're getting and the results you want to get? otherwise i cannot follow your code...

Comment: these are approximations of the theoretical values, but show how far off the results are.             case 1: 
   P(a < x <= b) :   0.7169  #should be 0.575        case 2: 
   P(a < x <= b) :   0.4282  #should be 0.3371        case 3: 
   P(a < x <= b) :   0.5966  #should be 0.4413        case 4: 
   P(a < x <= b) :   0.5595  #should be 0.2

Comment: what's the purpose of `1-random.random()` for random numbers between 0 and 1? the result is still random number between 0 and 1.

Comment: why did you choose a & b to be 0.9 and 1.8? the sum of two random distributions in range(0..1) tends to be symmetrical around 1.0, don't your limits need to be symmetrical too?